# ColdFusion RegEx Replacing Tags within a string

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to ReReplace the actual beginning/ending tags within a string.  
For example, I want to replace

```
<p class="style4">My Title Is This<p>
```

with

```
<h2>My Title Is This</h2>
```

I wrote the code below, which seems to find the tags properly within my string, but it's replacing it with `<h2>(.+?)</h2>


<cfset this.text2 = ReReplaceNoCase(getThis.statictext, '<p[^>]+class="style4"[^>]*>(.+?)</p>', '<h2>(.+?)</h2>', "ALL")>`

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a minute to learn about the awesome text formatting options in the editor (click the `?` icon). For example, to format text as code, just paste it, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K. No need to escape all the HTML entities yourself. Time well spent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of this: `'<h2>(.+?)</h2>'` you'll want to use the backreference `\1` to refer to the subexpression `(.+?)`:

```
<cfset this.text2 = ReReplaceNoCase(getThis.statictext, '<p\s[^>]+class="style4"[^>]*>(.+?)</p>', '<h2>\1</h2>', "ALL")>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**: Edited per Mike Causer's suggestion below.

Comment: you might want to put a `\s` after your opening `'<p` as you dont want it matching `<p*class="style4"...` but matching `<p *class="style4"...`

Comment: @MikeCauser, true! Good catch. I think the only case in which this could happen is the `<pre>` tag, but it is possible that others could be defined in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This finds all tags and just removes them,  you can easily modify this to do a replace.

```
<!--- 
# STRIPTAGS
# Strip all html tags from a string 
# Receive string and return string with any and all tags striped out
--->
<cffunction name="stripTags" access="public" output="false" returntype="string" hint="Remove all HTML tags from string">
    <cfargument name="string" type="any" required="true"  hint="String to clean"/>
    <cfset var pattern = "<[^>]*>">
    <cfreturn REReplaceNoCase(arguments.string, pattern, "" , "ALL")>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to strip all of the tags, I'm actually looking to replace one set of open/close tags with another.   I revised my message in order to better explain.

Comment: I think `<[^>]+>` would work better than `<[^>]*>` as the latter could match instances of `<>` while the former would match an actual tag. It still could match non-tags like `<1>` however.